# HIVE the unit of input size

Tags: hive

When I executed the hive, I got

**Estimated from input data size:1000**.

But, I did not know the unit of it.
Is it B, KB or GB?

Answer (score 1):

You have to look fro below [property](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist)

hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer on your hive configuration . As name suggests it is **bytes**.